# I'd like to paint an area but i don't know how to

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

[image: my plot]

I mean, I'd want to paint only the square area P1 X (Q1-Q2).

Not the trapezoid (P2+P1) X (Q1-Q2/2).

Here's code that I used. I used `ggplot` and `dplyr`. How can I solve this problem?

How can I paint the only square area not the trapezoied area!!!!

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
supply <- Hmisc::bezier(x = c(1, 8, 9),
                        y = c(1, 5, 9)) %>%
  as_data_frame()

demand <- Hmisc::bezier(c(1, 3, 9),
                        c(9, 3, 1)) %>%
  as_data_frame()


fun_supply <- approxfun(supply$x, supply$y, rule = 2)

fun_supply(c(2, 6, 8))
fun_demand <- approxfun(demand$x, demand$y, rule = 2)

intersection_funs <-  uniroot(function(x) fun_supply(x) - fun_demand(x), c(1, 9))
intersection_funs


y_root <- fun_demand(intersection_funs$root)


curve_intersect <- function(curve1, curve2) {
  # Approximate the functional form of both curves
  curve1_f <- approxfun(curve1$x, curve1$y, rule = 2)
  curve2_f <- approxfun(curve2$x, curve2$y, rule = 2)

  # Calculate the intersection of curve 1 and curve 2 along the x-axis
  point_x <- uniroot(function(x) curve1_f(x) - curve2_f(x), 
                     c(min(curve1$x), max(curve1$x)))$root

  # Find where point_x is in curve 2
  point_y <- curve2_f(point_x)

  # Finish 
  return(list(x = point_x, y = point_y))
}

intersection_xy <- curve_intersect(supply, demand)
intersection_xy
intersection_xy_df <- intersection_xy %>% as_data_frame()


demand2 <- Hmisc::bezier(c(1.5, 3.5, 9.5),
                         c(9.5, 3.5, 1.5)) %>%
  as_data_frame()

supply2 <- Hmisc::bezier(c(1,7,8),
                         c(3,7,11)) %>%
  as_data_frame()
#Make a data frame of the intersections of the supply curve and both demand curves

intersections <- bind_rows(curve_intersect(supply, demand),
                           curve_intersect(supply2, demand2))

plot_labels <- data_frame(label = c("S", "D","S[1]","D[1]"),
                          x = c(9, 1, 6.5, 3),
                          y = c(8, 8, 8, 8))



ggplot(mapping = aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_path(data = supply, color = "#0073D9", size = 1, linetype = "dashed") + 
  geom_path(data = demand, color = "#FF4036", size = 1, linetype = "dashed") + 
  geom_path(data = demand2, color = "#FF4036", size = 1) + 
  geom_path(data = supply2, color = "#0073D9", size = 1) +
  geom_segment(data = intersections, 
               aes(x = x, y = 0, xend = x, yend = y), lty = "dotted") +
  geom_segment(data = intersections, 
               aes(x = 0, y = y, xend = x, yend = y), lty = "dotted") + 
  geom_segment(data = intersections,
               aes(x = x, y = y, xend = x, yend=  y), lty = "dotted") +
  geom_point(data = intersections, size = 3) +
  geom_text(data = plot_labels,
            aes(x = x, y = y, label = label), parse = TRUE) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), breaks = intersections$x,
                     labels = expression(Q[1], Q[2])) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), breaks = intersections$y,
                     labels = expression(P[1], P[2]))+
  labs(x = "Quantity", y = "Price") +
  geom_area(data =intersections, fill="#9999FF", alpha=0.5) +
  theme_classic() + 
  coord_equal()
```

---

Could you help me to paint the area that I mentioned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might try adding `geom_rect(data=intersections[1,], aes(xmin=0, xmax=x, ymin=0, ymax=y),fill='green', alpha=0.5)` to your plot call.

So we have:

```
ggplot(mapping = aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_path(data = supply, color = "#0073D9", size = 1, linetype = "dashed") + 
  geom_path(data = demand, color = "#FF4036", size = 1, linetype = "dashed") + 
  geom_path(data = demand2, color = "#FF4036", size = 1) + 
  geom_path(data = supply2, color = "#0073D9", size = 1) +
  geom_segment(data = intersections, 
               aes(x = x, y = 0, xend = x, yend = y), lty = "dotted") +
  geom_segment(data = intersections, 
               aes(x = 0, y = y, xend = x, yend = y), lty = "dotted") + 
  geom_segment(data = intersections,
               aes(x = x, y = y, xend = x, yend=  y), lty = "dotted") +
  geom_point(data = intersections, size = 3) +
  geom_text(data = plot_labels,
            aes(x = x, y = y, label = label), parse = TRUE) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), breaks = intersections$x,
                     labels = expression(Q[1], Q[2])) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), breaks = intersections$y,
                     labels = expression(P[1], P[2]))+
  labs(x = "Quantity", y = "Price") +
  geom_area(data =intersections, fill="#9999FF", alpha=0.5) +
  theme_classic() + 
  coord_equal()+
  geom_rect(data=intersections[1,], aes(xmin=0, xmax=x, ymin=0, ymax=y),fill='green', alpha=0.5)
```

[image]

Edit based on comment:

`geom_rect(data=intersections, aes(xmin=x[2], xmax=x[1], ymin=0, ymax=y[1]),fill='green', alpha=0.5)`

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for giving solution for me. You save me!!!!
 
Can I ask one more question? 
How can I paint only the square (Q1-Q2)*P1 ?
I mean, not the the big square Q1*P1 , but the small square (Q1-Q2)*P1 .

Comment: @hyejuryu if you feel this answer answered your question, feel free to accept it by checking the check mark under the voting score. If you have more questions not directly related to this, open a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Though the answer from J Con is in depth and does provide a solution, a cleaner approach in ggplot2 may be to use the [annotate](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/annotate.html) function, with `geom` and other arguments set appropriately. (See link for help page.)

This is because using something like `geom_rect` involves passing positions and so on as a data.frame, which is a bit more of a hack as, conceptually, from a grammar of graphics perspective, the data layer and the annotation layer are distinct: the act of mapping data variables to graphical aesthetics in a systematic and objective way, and of marking up features within the dataset in a piecemeal and subjective way, are separate activities, and using `annotate` explicitly for the latter purpose makes this divide clearer in terms of the code and concepts.

### Edit

To be more specific, the `annotate` equivalent of the following:

```
geom_rect(data=intersections, aes(xmin=x[2], xmax=x[1], ymin=0, ymax=y[1]),fill='green', alpha=0.5)
```

Would likely be as follows

```
annotate(
   geom = "rect",
   xmin = intersections$x[2], x = intersections$x[1],
   ymin = 0, ymax = intersections$y[1],
   fill = 'green', alpha = 0.5
)
```

Functionally this is exactly the same, but conceptually it makes the separation between the data layer and the annotation layer much clearer in the code expressed.

Note: Annotate could also be used for the points and text.

Comment: is it possible to show the "illustrated" version of your proposed approach. It sounds interesting and I would like to see how something as disparate as `annotate` can serve to answer this question.